# Delete the duplicate observations if a column contains particular text in R dataframe

Tags: r, string, dataframe, subset

I have an R dataframe that has duplicate rows as follows:

```
X1         X10
rs6908903  chr6
rs6908903  chr6_GL000251v2_alt
rs6908903  chr6_GL000252v2_alt
rs6908903  chr6_GL000252v2_alt
rs6908903  chr6_GL000252v2_alt
```

In this case, I want to create a new df containing only the first row (Chr6) and delete rows containing the char GL000

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try `grepl`:

```
df[!grepl('GL000', df$X2),]
```

Comment: OK! this worked well. I now noticed that there are different strings other than GL after "Chr6_". 

How can I remove the observations which contain some characters after the chr6_ and only keep observations with Chr6?

Comment: @Mahan `df[grepl('^chr6$', df$X2),]`

Comment: OK. Let me clarify - my df contains the values as below

chr1
chr2
chr3
chr4
chr5
chr8
chr9
chr8_KZ208915v1_fix
chr5_GL339449v2_alt

In this case, I want to keep all the rows except the last two.

Comment: @Mahan `df[grepl('^chr\d+$', df$X2),]`

Comment: Error: '\d' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "'^chr\d"

Comment: @Mahan A typo `df[grepl('^chr\\d+$', df$X2),]`

Answer (score 1):

Just to offer an alternative here is one using `dplyr` and `stringr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df <- data.frame(X1 =c("rs6908903","rs6908903","rs6908903","rs6908903","rs6908903"),X10=c("chr6","chr6_GL000251v2_alt","chr6_GL000252v2_alt","chr6_GL000252v2_alt","chr6_GL000252v2_alt"))

 df %>% filter(!str_detect(X10, 'GL000'))
```

Output:

```
         X1  X10
1 rs6908903 chr6
```

Edit:

```
df %>% 
  dplyr::filter(!grepl('_', X10))
```

Output:

```
         X1  X10
1 rs6908903 chr6
```

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion. But I want to keep observations that have chromosome names like "chr2", "chr16" but delete any row which has values like "chr8_KZ208915v1_fix" "chr5_GL339449v2_alt". I want to get rid of any rows containing some strings after "_"

Comment: @Mahan I have edited my answer, is that what you're looking for?